# As a client, how to avoid CLOSE_WAIT in TCP/IP socket in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I want to connect to the localhost port 6667 iteratively to get some data. The code is like this:

```
def get_data_from_socket(n):
    # making a socket
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

        # resolving localhost’s ip
        host_ip = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')

        # connecting to the server
        s.connect((host_ip, 6667))

        # output the client socket ip and port 
        print('getsockname:{}'.format(s.getsockname()))

        # listening the port
        while True:

            # send message to the server
            s.sendall('get: {}'.format(str(n)).encode())

            # Getting a response from the server
            res = (s.recv(1024)).decode()

            # if the length of messages is not empty, stop listening the port.
            if len(res) > 0:
                # stop listening
                break
return res

def get_all_data_from_socket():
    res = ''
    for i in range(5):
         res += get_data_from_socket(i)
    return res
```

I run `python get_all_data_from_socket()` once and get the following output in the terminal:

```
getsockname:('127.0.0.1', 43230)
getsockname:('127.0.0.1', 43232)
getsockname:('127.0.0.1', 43234)
```

After that, if I run the following command

```
sudo netstat -tonp | grep CLOSE_WAIT
```

I always get a `CLOSE_WAIT` connection, for example:

```
tcp6       1      0 127.0.0.1:6666          127.0.0.1:43230         CLOSE_WAIT  290779/java          off (0.00/0/0)
```

Why is that my code does not always close the connection when it runs the function `get_data_from_socket()`? It seems always to be the first connection that it does not close. Any ideas?

Comment: The first address in `netstat` is the local address, which mean it is the server socket that isn't closed, not the client socket. Also, small nitpick: _listening_ is a term generally used for a server socket, not for a connection socket.

Comment: @ElderBug I did not show all results from `netstat` regarding to the local address port `6666` which indeed is a listening port, and use `netstat -an | grep 6666`, I have also: `tcp6       0      0 :::6666                 :::*                    LISTEN ` which should be the one you mentioned. I just do not understand why it does not close the connection and keeps it as `CLOSE_WAIT`.

Comment: There are 3 sockets involved in a connection: The server listening socket (the one in your comment), and two connections sockets, one server side and one client side. The open one you showed is the _server_ socket. Which means your client (the code you posted), correctly closed all the sockets. It is the server program that doesn't close the socket. The bug isn't in the code you posted.

Comment: @ElderBug Thanks a lot!